# Rust Vulkano how to reuse command buffer

Tags: rust, vulkan

I've precomputed one command buffer per frame and now I'd like to submit them in loop. I have this piece of code so far

```
let command_buffer = &command_buffers[image_num];
let future = previous_frame_end
    .take()
    .unwrap()
    .join(acquire_future)
    .then_execute(queue.clone(), command_buffer)
    .unwrap()
    .then_swapchain_present(queue.clone(), swapchain.clone(), image_num)
    .then_signal_fence_and_flush();
```

However this yields

```
                       let command_buffer = &command_buffers[image_num];
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `&PrimaryAutoCommandBuffer` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   --> src\main.rs:442:22
    |
442 |                     .then_execute(queue.clone(), command_buffer)
```

I can see that the function expects static lifetime

```
    fn then_execute<Cb>(
        self,
        queue: Arc<Queue>,
        command_buffer: Cb,
    ) -> Result<CommandBufferExecFuture<Self, Cb>, CommandBufferExecError>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        Cb: PrimaryCommandBuffer + 'static,
```

Perhaps I should clone this buffer similarly to the way it's done here

https://github.com/bwasty/vulkan-tutorial-rs/blob/f2f6935914bec4e79937b8cac415683c9fbadcb1/src/bin/15_hello_triangle.rs#L523

However, In version `vulkano = "0.24.0"` cloning is no longer implemented for `PrimaryCommandBuffer`

Comment: You could make a `static reference?

Comment: But the buffer itself is not static.

Comment: Hm, maybe `std::sync::Arc`. Seems to work in cursory test...